# How to hide canceled/deleted events in Google Calendar, when syncing events from Exchange?

Tags: google-calendar

I'm using the latest version of Google Calendar on Android 5 to sync events from an Exchange server. However canceled and deleted events keep showing up in the Calendar, even though I no longer see them on the Exchange server.

Is there a way to hide or delete them from Google Calendar as well?

Comment: I'm afraid your question is off-topic here. If you were asking about Google Calendar using the desktop web app, it would be fine, but questions about Android apps belong at [android.se]. I'm going to flag this question and suggest it be migrated there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an Android app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 2017 it's impossible to hide cancelled events from Google Calendar. So unfortunately you would have to delete them manually.